# Is it safe to upgrade to Eclipse Juno.

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-juno

Last time I tried it was riddled with performance issues. Does anyone know if it's safe to upgrade yet ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply upgrade to 3.8 instead of 4.2. All the improvements in JDT, PDE and related tools are the same, but you do not get the new CSS styled, modeled workbench, which is mostly responsible for the performance issues.

See this answer for a more detailed explanation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12381204/44089

Comment: So it seems effectively the answer is still no. Thanks

Comment: Not really. 3.8 and 4.2 are *both* Juno. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is effectively true that Eclipse Juno (4.2) has lots of performance issues.

I do not know if the performance issues you encounter will be fixed but you may wait for the Juno SR2 release which is planned for February 22nd.

A lot of work seems to be done on performance issues for the next major release (Eclipse 4.3 planned for June).

Answer (score 1):

The performance seems better, but Juno SR2 has been [delayed one week though](http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/cross-project-issues-dev/msg08715.html).

> After some painful conversation with the Planning Council members, the conclusion was to delay the release 1 week, but not do a full respin, to only revert the EGit contribution.
>
> The plan is to redo the common repository and EPP packages, with the EGit contribution reverted to what it was in SR1, which I believe is identical to what it was in RC3.
> There are a few "technical tricks" I can try to accomplish this, so all other projects do not have to do any re-work ... just wait until Friday 3/1, before making your releases "visible".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade right now, you should consider the designated performance patches: [Eclipse Juno slow to switch tabs in editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805109/eclipse-juno-slow-to-switch-tabs-in-editor/14029933#14029933)