# How can I tell if I am on Juno SR1 or Juno SR2?

Tags: eclipse

Based on this dialog, how can I tell if I am on Juno SR1 or Juno SR2?

[image]

Do I look at Eclipse Platform, or Eclipse RCP? Or is there some other place I should be looking at instead?

**Edit #1:** This was taken on Spring Toolsuite, and I have updated to the latest versions via Help > Check for Updates. Help > About would show 3.3.0.RELEASE.

Comment: For the love of all that is holy or sacred, do not use juno. Use kepler, Juno is full of bugs and bad ideas. I know because I was forced to use it.

Comment: @GamesBrainiac Thanks for the heads up. But for now, we are on Juno, since we're using a custom Eclipse build (by the company) that's based on Juno.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's neither.  You're seeing a CVS Client feature that's dated months after Juno SR2 (it's more in line with Kepler) along with an Eclipse Platform feature that roughly corresponds to Juno SR1.  That said, unless this is merely an academic thought experiment, what's this supposed to be an answer to?

Comment: I was trying to figure out which Juno SR verion I am on. Before I updated (still on Juno), switch tabs was very slow. After update, it improved, but I don't know if it's SR1 or SR2. The slow issue is described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13805109/eclipse-juno-slow-to-switch-tabs-in-editor

Comment: As described in my Edit #1, I am on STS that runs on top of Juno. Well, I want to know which Juno SR it is - 1 or 2.

Comment: It's still neither, but performance fixes were introduced after SR1 had already gone out the door.

Answer (score 1):

Am not sure how to see the version from the dialog you shown above, but
Just go to Help -> About you should see

[image]

Comment: Added Edit#1 to my question.

Answer (score 0):

SR is **service release**.
go to Help-> about and check if service release version is 1 or 2